# send bootup script output to virtual terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, login

I have a script that I symlink in as `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S30initialize` which basically makes it get called when entering runlevel 3.

I want for the output of this script to appear on the virtual terminal. For example on the default display of the screen. So what I do inside this script is wrap everything inside

```
(
  set -e
  set -x

  .... install some stuff, etc

) 2>&1 | tee -a /etc/init.log > /dev/tty1
```

So this works fine but what happens is that the stream of output makes it to the screen just fine (at the end of the bootup kernel messages) but then the tty login prompt comes up and "covers it up" about a second later.

At the end of the script execution I can often spot logged into `/etc/init.log` this:

```
tee: write error
```

Sooooo my question is, is there some way that I can temporarily or permanently disable the tty login prompt on `tty1`? I'm quite happy to use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to log in to the machine if I need to.

I have also tried changing it to not use a pipe, like this: `) 2>&1 | tee -a /etc/init.log /dev/tty1` but this suffers from the same problem (it just no longer seems to produce a `tee: write error` error).

I'm mostly interested in tweaking this behavior on Centos 7.

Incidentally when i try to do similar things on my Raspberry Pi I did use a slightly different method of running things at startup: there I added commands to `rc.local`, and everything makes its way to the main terminal screen without a problem.

So maybe I can try that, or there is maybe another way -- maybe I can put in a long pause to wait for the login prompt to show up before I run the subshell which is being directed to `/dev/tty1`. This way instead of the login prompt stomping on the output stream it will be my script stomping on the output stream.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Init scripts should never write to terminals - write to a log file.

Comment: I already log to a file. Reading comprehension is important :)

Comment: So why do you still try to write to a terminal? Not doing stupid things is also important - perhaps moreso.

Comment: Just because you think something is stupid doesn't make it a bad question. Please. We're not here to argue. Well, I'm not.